# many to many symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many

I'm trying to set up a multiple choice form with many to many relationship but I keep getting this Error message "Unable to transform value for property path "rozmiar": Expected an array." This is How my Entity looks like:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Rozmiar")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="buty__rozmiary",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="buty_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="rozmiar_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $rozmiar;
 /**
 * Set rozmiar
 *
 * @param ArrayCollection $rozmiar
 * @return rozmiar
 */
public function setRozmiar($rozmiar)
{
    $this->rozmiar = $rozmiar;
    return $this;

}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getRozmiar()
{
    return $this->rozmiar;
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->rozmiar = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And my form:

```
->add('rozmiar', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices' => [35,36,37,38,39,40]
            )
        )
```

What should I do to get this to work? Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
I changed the part of my FORM to

```
->add('rozmiar', EntityType::class, array( 
'class' => 'ShoeShopBundle:Buty',
'expanded' => true,
'multiple' => true,
'choices' => [35,36,37,38,39,40] ))
```

and now I'm getting "Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given" error. What is the proper way to define choices in this kind of field?

Comment: Have you trying to set expanded to false ?

Comment: You have to use `EntityType` field http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: Ok, so when I use EntityType field like this: `->add('rozmiar', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'ShoeShopBundle:Buty',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                )
            )` it works, but how can I define the choice option list? Do i have to define it in the controller? When i'm using `'choices' => [35,36,37,38,39,40]` I'm getting "Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given"

Answer (score 0):

You need an EntityType field

```
->add('rozmiar', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Rozmiar',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => $editedObject->getRozmiarChoices(),
))
```

with

```
$editedObject = $builder->getData();
```

be carefull to edit addRozmiar Method for the added rozmiar to know that new link :

```
public function addRozmiar(\MyBundle\Entity\Rozmiar $rozmiar)
{
    if (!$this->rozmiar->contains($rozmiar)) {
        $this->rozmiar->add($rozmiar);
        $rozmiar->addButy($this);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

in Symfony2 I also often needed to add this value in the form, in order to force your method usage :
`'by_reference' => false,`

more infos : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

---

Edit :

Your choice list need to be an array or an arrayCollection of objects of class "MyBundle:Rozmiar". not integers.
You can also use the 'query_builder' option instead of the 'choices' one if the list is not specificly related to your edited object.

see here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Your list [35,36,37,38,39,40] shouldn't be hard coded in your form.
You should put it in your entity if this is an enum, or add a boolean field in your other table in ordrer to use the query builder to find them.

I hope this will help :)

Comment: It's a form for another Entity called Buty (ButyForm) so i have to define getRozmiarChoices method in it? How do i have to get the getDoctrine method work in entity definition?

Comment: Thanks for the help, now it's working. Maybe you know how to make multiselection list (where you don't need to push ctrl to select more than 1 option) instead of checkboxes?

Comment: What do you mean by multiselection list ?

Comment: I mean a drop down list with multiple selection? I gave you a thumb up, but since i've got less than 15 reputation it's just not changing public post score ;) Could you please try helping my with another issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106506/symfony-2-files-upload

Comment: 'expanded' => false,