# Symfony2 file upload fails when second file field is added

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm trying to upload 2 images with 2 form fields. My form:

```
        ->add('zdjecie', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Zdjecie (img file)'))
        ->add('zdjecieMIN', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Zdjecie miniatura (img file)'))
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Dodaj zdjecie miniaturke")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg",})
 */
private $zdjecieMIN;

public function getZdjecieMIN()
{
    return $this->zdjecieMIN;
}

public function setZdjecieMIN($zdjecieMIN)
{
    $this->zdjecieMIN = $zdjecieMIN;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Dodaj zdjecie")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg",})
 */
private $zdjecie;

public function getZdjecie()
{
    return $this->zdjecie;
}

public function setZdjecie($zdjecie)
{
    $this->zdjecie = $zdjecie;

    return $this;
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $buty = new Buty();
    $form = $this->createForm('ShoeShopBundle\Form\ButyType', $buty);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $file = $buty->getZdjecie();
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('img_directory'),
            $fileName
        );
        $buty->setZdjecie($fileName);

        $file2 = $buty->getZdjecieMIN();
        $fileName2 = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file2->move(
            $this->getParameter('img_directory'),
            $fileName2
        );
        $buty->setZdjecieMIN($fileName2);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($buty);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin_buty_show', array('id' => $buty->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('ShoeShopBundle:Admin/Buty:new.html.twig', array(
        'buty' => $buty,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Config:

```
parameters:
locale: en
img_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/img'
```

Everything was ok when I was using only 1 image upload field but now im getting "The file "C:\xampp\tmp\phpBF79.tmp" does not exist " error, anyone know what's wrong?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: Added my html/twig form

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="adm-new">
<h2>Dodaj nowy produkt</h2>

{{ form_start(form) }}
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.marka) }}
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.marka) }}:
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.marka) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.model) }}
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.model) }}:
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.model) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.kolor) }}
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.kolor) }}:
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.kolor) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.cena) }}
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.cena) }}:
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.cena) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.rozmiar) }}
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.rozmiar) }}:
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.rozmiar) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.zdjecieMIN) }}
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.zdjecieMIN) }}:
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.zdjecieMIN) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.zdjecie) }}
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.zdjecie) }}:
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.zdjecie) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Dodaj" /></div>
{{ form_end(form) }}

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('app_admin_buty_index') }}">Powrot do listy produktow</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your model only allows for one image. Try creating a `Zdjecie` class that holds a `file`, and a `zdjecies` property on your main class that has a `@OneToMany` doctrine directive, pointing at the new class.

Comment: Why my model allows only one image? Should't I just change the main entity in some way? If I use one to many form then i have to put one image in one column and second in another column, can I do it in main entity form?

Comment: But Form != Model. Check this out: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I know Form!= Model, sorry, my question wasn't clear (it's late and I'm not thinking straight), If I use one to many directive how am I going to know which image is which (i need to use them in different views)? If i use one to one directive and make separate columns for each picture in that new Zdjecie class,am I going to be able to fill both of them in just one main form? (sorry I hadn't checked your link yet, i'm going to do this first thing in the morning, just needed to clear this out before going to sleep ;) )

Comment: My bad, I didn't read closely. You do have two file props. Ignore me!

Comment: so you don't know how o fix my code so this error would stop blocking my app?:(

Comment: I do apologize @Paweł -- I have a suspicion that perhaps the form is rendered improperly, though. Could you show us the twig / html from the front-end?

Comment: I added my ftont-end form code but i don't think that this it's the source of the problem :)

Comment: You're probably right. I took a different tack with my answer just now. Hope I can redeem myself for not reading closely the first time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suspicion that `uniqid` is generating the same filename for both uploads, and that that is the heart of the file-not-found issue you're seeing.

From the PHP docs:

> ### [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)
>
> Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds.

Both calls to `uniqid` are executed close enough together that based on the time-in-microseconds part of the function, it might assign them both the same name. Therefore, the second one will be "missing" when you go to `$file->move` *it*.

Try subbing in [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php), for a far lesser likelihood of file name collisions. You can also mitigate this possibility by calling `getBasename` on the `$file`, and concatenating that to the string passed to `md5`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Camerun Hurd suggested it was a problem with uniqid generating the same filename for both files. mt_rand() function gave the same result so I just changed

```
$file2 = $buty->getZdjecieMIN();
    $fileName2 = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
    $file2->move(
        $this->getParameter('img_directory'),
        $fileName2
    );
    $buty->setZdjecieMIN($fileName2);
```

in my controller to:

```
$ext_pos = strrpos($fileName, '.');

        $file2 = $buty->getZdjecieMIN();
        $fileName2 = substr($fileName, 0, $ext_pos) . '_min' . substr($fileName, $ext_pos);;
        $file2->move(
            $this->getParameter('img_directory'),
            $fileName2
        );
        $buty->setZdjecieMIN($fileName2);
```

Thanks Cameron and rodd from #symfony for all the help.

Comment: Hey @PawełP -- If my answer was indeed the correct one, would you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score -1):

I think it not solve your problem but you check in file2name extension from file not from file2.
If you move file to another place maybe it's problem with guessExtension() on moved file.

Comment: That's the full error log: "CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException: "The file "C:\xampp\tmp\php76BA.tmp" does not exist" at C:\xampp\htdocs\Sklep\shoeShop\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesser.php line 123" I tried storing second image in another directory but it didn't help.